# Code after event fire is not executing | Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, events, broadcast

I'm firing a status update event to broadcast on pusher. That's all working fine, however the code after the event fire doesnt work. At all.
Even if i put dd("hello"); nothing comes up. If i remove the event fire, things work as expected. I need this to work as i have a different redirect based on object parameter as shown below.
I can't figure out why this is happening, thanks for the help!

```
        {
            $room->start($connector);

            event(new RoomStatusUpdated($room)); //problem here

            if($room->autoLogin==1)
            {
                return redirect(route("room.join", $room->id));
            }
            else
            {
                notify()->info("","Meeting has started","bottomRight");
                return back();
            }

        }
```

Comment: did u define it in `EventServiceProvider` ?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing Event and/or Listener code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 event(new RoomStatusUpdated($room)); //problem here
```

if your **`QUEUE_DRIVE=sync`**, Better you need  to double  check your event call as the event needs  to be successful. Best practice is to include a temporary Logger by putting try-catch to your event

```
try{
   //your event call
}catch(\Exception e){
   Log::info("Code got excited: Line: {$e->getLine()} with error message:  {$e->getMessage()}");
}
```

if queue driver is using a external like sqs or azure put back to sync first to trace back your event.